# Mavericks Spotlight Can't Find Files

Tags: macos, spotlight

i am looking at a file in finder (/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.6-p420/gems/mysql2-0.3.17/lib/mysql2.rb   ---- I'm listing all this in case Spotlight can's go this deep).

i ask spotlight to find it --- typing in upper finder window "mysql2" or "mysql2." or "mysql2.rb".

No results.

I looked thru all the similar questions. I've gone to System Preferences and drug the whole disk onto the privacy tab. I've taken the disk off that tab and just selected one small directory there. Supposedly if you close it (preferences) it will index the disk and then find your file.

No go.

I'm really getting frustrated. Can somebody tell me if there is another configure option somewhere. Or if not, is there a "after-market" search app that is good. I have to be able to look up files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OS X treats folders that start with a "." as hidden, and Spotlight doesn't search them.

You could use *find* in the Terminal.app to find files. In your situation:

```
find ~/ -iname mysql2.rb
```

I've never searched for after-market apps because I can find anything I want using the command line.

HTH,

Comment: mdfind in terminal does it as well.

Comment: On my system, mdfind doesn't appear to search hidden folders either.